# How does nav-justified worked?

Tags: css, w3c

I surprised that any number of elements can be sized to have same width  regardless elements count with two lines of CSS:

```
display: table-cell;
width: 1%;
```

For following code:

```
<div style="width: 50%">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Long link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

each `li` has width `50%/4 = 12.5%`.

Both line of CSS code is essential to make trick. Does anyone explain how that works in term of W3C specs?

**UPDATE** Another useful addition to trick is `li { text-align: center; }`.

Comment: Why not read the specs and find out?

Comment: Because I am not tech person that able to understand specs?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-layout